# Java program freezes on call to any method of a particular class

Tags: java, class, methods, static, static-methods

I have an application that I am working on that decided to stop working in a very unexplained manner. After some debugging and error tracing, I found the problem to be in the call to a specific method in my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Print ");
    InternalPanel.init();
}

IN INTERNAL PANEL

public static void init() {
    System.out.println("Line");
}
```

Just to clarify, calling **any other** methods from other classes works. Calling **any** methods from this specific class does not work.

Also, this class (and methods within) have always worked.

When it stopped working, I was making minor changes to something completely irrelevant in the program (As in, in a separate thread, having no effect on the class in question)

Comment: what if you revert the change?

Comment: This particularly innocuous system call doesn't seem to be capable of causing a hang.  Go through your code judiciously with a powerful debugger and see what's going on at every step of your program call.

Comment: Does `InternalPanel` have any kind of static initialization? If so, please show that code.

Comment: This question is way too vague.

Comment: `InternalPanel` is this a Swing program? Should be doing all component manipulation on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) (use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` and lots of boilerplate). Also mutable statics/global state is bad. / What are the other threads doing? - use your debugger, `jstack`, ctrl-\/ctrl-break, or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the rest of your InternalPanel class. It's likely that something in its static initialization has an effect on something else. For example:

```
public class InternalPanel
{
    private static SomeOtherThing thing = new SomeOtherThing();
    ...
}
```

In the above code, if instantiating SomeOtherThing ends up causing a chain of events that eventually produces an infinite loop or a stack overflow, that would produce the effect you're seeing. It wouldn't actually be the call to the `init` function, but rather the static initialization of the InternalPanel class.

(You could easily check if this is a static initialization issue by having your test program invoke some other dummy method on the `InternalPanel` class.)

In debug mode, you may just want to try pausing execution at random while the program appears to be frozen, and see what code is being run and what the stack trace looks like.

Comment: Brilliant. This solved the reason why it is not working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The above code works perfectly for me with just those two base classes.  This is expected, as it's not really doing all that much.

I would:

1. Perform a clean build in your IDE (mvn clean, Eclipse->(Menu)->Clean etc.)
2. Trace (Despite what you said, I'm suggesting it anyway) to see if init() is reached.
3. Check you don't have a `static { }`  'constructor' method in any other classes.

Answer (score 0):

As already implied by others:
What happens is, that the class InternalPanel gets loaded through the ClassLoader, if it has not been used before. That class might depend on other classes, which might get loaded and that recurses until all required classes are loaded.

For all loaded classes the static initializers are invoked. In one of those static initializers some kind of locking might be happening, causing your application to hang.

Try setting a [class load breakpoint](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#advanced_class) to see, if loading the class might be the issue.